# How to set jersey in spring boot 1.4.1-RELEASE to convert dates to ISO 8601?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0, iso8601

In Spring boot 1.3.6-RELEASE I had the below class registered to jersey. Every java.util.Date field would be read and returned as ISO8601 format. However, when updating to 1.4.1-RELEASE it now sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. What's the new proper way to enable this?

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601Utils;

@Provider
public class DateTimeParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> clazz, Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (type.equals(Date.class)) {
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new DateTimeParamConverter();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static class DateTimeParamConverter implements ParamConverter<Date> {
        @Override
        public java.util.Date fromString(String value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                return ISO8601Utils.parse(value, new ParsePosition(0));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(Date value) {
            return ISO8601Utils.format(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I register this provider like this:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JerseyConfiguration.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    public JerseyConfiguration(LogRequestFilter lrf) {
        register(new ObjectMapperContextResolverNonNull());
        register(RestServiceImpl.class);
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
        register(DateTimeParamConverterProvider.class, 6000);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define this in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
```